# Clear Earlier Dates in End date Calendar using ajaxControlToolkit:calendarExtender

Tags: c#

If from date is selected in calendar Extender, I need to clear previous dates than from date from To Date Calendar as shown in figure. Please provide your comments

[image: End date Calendar]

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS property on your any .css class

```
.ajax__calendar_day_disabled
{
    background-color:#ccc !important;
    color:#eee !important;
}
```

use above css class in date textbox like `CssClass="disable_past_dates"`
and use script

`function getElementsByClassName(a, b) { var c = []; var d = a.getElementsByTagName("*"); for (var e = 0; e < d.length; e++) { if (d[e].className.indexOf(b) != -1) { c.push(d[e]) } } return c } function DisableDates(a) { if (a._element.className.indexOf("disable_past_dates") != -1) { var b = getElementsByClassName(a._days, "ajax__calendar_day"); var c = (new Date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); for (var d = 0; d < b.length; d++) { try { if (b[d].date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) >= c) { b[d].className = "ajax__calendar_day" } else { b[d].className = "ajax__calendar_day ajax__calendar_day_disabled" } } catch (e) { } } } if (a._element.className.indexOf("disable_future_dates") != -1) { var b = getElementsByClassName(a._days, "ajax__calendar_day"); var c = (new Date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); for (var d = 0; d < b.length; d++) { try { if (b[d].date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) <= c) { b[d].className = "ajax__calendar_day" } else { b[d].className = "ajax__calendar_day ajax__calendar_day_disabled" } } catch (e) { } } } } AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarBehavior.prototype.show = function (a) { this._ensureCalendar(); if (!this._isOpen) { var b = new Sys.CancelEventArgs; this.raiseShowing(b); if (b.get_cancel()) { return } this._isOpen = true; this._popupBehavior.show(); if (this._firstPopUp) { this._switchMonth(null, true); switch (this._defaultView) { case AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarDefaultView.Months: this._switchMode("months", true); break; case AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarDefaultView.Years: this._switchMode("years", true); break } this._firstPopUp = false } this.raiseShown(); DisableDates(this) } }; AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarBehavior.prototype._cell_onclick = function (a) { a.stopPropagation(); a.preventDefault(); if (!this._enabled) return; var b = a.target; var c = this._getEffectiveVisibleDate(); Sys.UI.DomElement.removeCssClass(b.parentNode, "ajax__calendar_hover"); switch (b.mode) { case "prev": case "next": this._switchMonth(b.date); break; case "title": switch (this._mode) { case "days": this._switchMode("months"); break; case "months": this._switchMode("years"); break } break; case "month": if (b.month == c.getMonth()) { this._switchMode("days") } else { this._visibleDate = b.date; this._switchMode("days") } break; case "year": if (b.date.getFullYear() == c.getFullYear()) { this._switchMode("months") } else { this._visibleDate = b.date; this._switchMode("months") } break; case "day": if (this._element.className.indexOf("disable_past_dates") != -1) { if (b.date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) >= (new Date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) { this.set_selectedDate(b.date); this._switchMonth(b.date); this._blur.post(true); this.raiseDateSelectionChanged() } } else if (this._element.className.indexOf("disable_future_dates") != -1) { if (b.date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) <= (new Date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) { this.set_selectedDate(b.date); this._switchMonth(b.date); this._blur.post(true); this.raiseDateSelectionChanged() } } else { this.set_selectedDate(b.date); this._switchMonth(b.date); this._blur.post(true); this.raiseDateSelectionChanged() } break; case "today": this.set_selectedDate(b.date); this._switchMonth(b.date); this._blur.post(true); this.raiseDateSelectionChanged(); break } DisableDates(this) };`

This will disabled all the past dates but not clears it.

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
CntrlID.MinDate = DateTime.Now;

CntrlID.MaxDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(12);

CntrlID.MaxDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(100);
```